# android - out of memory in large screen - change image fast

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, imageview, out-of-memory

i want to change one image in my screen fast. it has'nt any problem on htc desire s or sumsung  s1. but when install app on s3 or large screen device. the image changing slowly and after a while force close app. the error is: "Out of memory on a 6354208-byte allocation."i change my image resolution and it works better but the error is'nt fix and sometimes occurred. used memory in s3 is 35 mb!!!

```
        float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
            / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
    long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (accelationSquareRoot >= 1.5) //
    {
        if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 30) {

            return;
        }
        Random r=new Random();
        randomWord+=r.nextInt(3);
        randomWord%=4;
        lastUpdate = actualTime;

        isStarted=true;
//          ((BitmapDrawable)shakedButton.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
        switch (randomWord) {
        case 0:
            shakedButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.alef);
            break;
        case 1:
            shakedButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
            break;
        case 2:
            shakedButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.jim);
            break;
        case 3:
            shakedButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.dal);
            break;


        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to reduce the memory usage of you app. you should be using less than 16mb at all times.

Comment: each of 4 images has only 38 KB size

Comment: you can resize the images, reuse object, etc. http://blog.gorges.us/2010/07/developing-apps-within-androids-16mb-memory-limit/

Comment: you could also suggest the GC to run before doing something memory intensive. `System.gc();`

Comment: What is your TargetSdkVersion and MinSdkVersion

Comment: OutOfMemory Occurs for them since their screen resolution is large and  obviosly Bitmap size will be More

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use canvas and result is so good

I write this class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {

private int imageIndex;

private int dstWidth;
private int dstHeight;
private int x, y;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    imageIndex = 0;

    dstWidth = 265;
    dstHeight = 240;

    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Bitmap harf;

    if( imageIndex == 0 )
        harf = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.alef);
    else if( imageIndex == 1 )
        harf = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.b );
    else if( imageIndex == 2 )
        harf = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.jim );
    else
        harf = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.dal );

    Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( harf, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x, y, null);     
}

public void setIndexAndDraw( int index )
{
    imageIndex = index;
    invalidate();
}
}
```

I initialized shakedView this way in onCreate method

```
    MyView shakedView;
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    lp.leftMargin=70;
    shakedView=new MyView(this);
    rLayout.addView(shakedView,lp);
```

and my code in the question change in this way

```
if (accelationSquareRoot >= 1.5) //
    {
        if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 30) {

            return;
        }
        Random r=new Random();
        randomWord+=r.nextInt(3);
        randomWord%=4;
        lastUpdate = actualTime;
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isStarted=true;
        shakedView.setIndexAndDraw(randomWord);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your Target is From Api level 10 you can use Android:largeHeap="true" in Application Tag see the following [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)